# Store number of rows in mysql data in variable

Tags: python, mysql

```
SELECT COUNT( *) as "Number of Rows"
FROM orders;
```

i want to add "Number of rows" into a python variable but idk how.

Comment: I see no python code in your question, just SQL query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

stored numbers of rows in python variables

```
db= MySQLdb.connect("HOSTNAME", "USER_NAME", "PWD", "DB_NAME");
cursor= db.cursor();
number_of_rows = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBL");
print(number_of_rows);
```

Comment: I doubt that it will work properly. I am not familiar with MySQLdb, but generally you should fetch data from cursor after query. It should be something like `cursor.fetchone()` which returns you row with single column containing result of `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

The result of any SQL Query statement is always a set, which then must be processed as a set by running the cursor over the result set. No SQL Query statement ever returns a value. So, Olvin you are right; the given example is plain wrong.